# Option Strict On disallows late binding in VB6 migrated code

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I have migrated a VB6 control to Vb.Net and when I had option strict on, I am getting "Option Strict On disallows late binding" error. Below I have mentioned VB6 code as well as migrated code in detail.

VB6 Code:-

```
Private m_colRows As Collection    'Represents the rows in a table
Private m_lngCurrCol As Long 'Control variable for Col Property
Private m_lngCurrRow As Long 'Control variable for Row Property

Public Property Let CellText(ByVal strText As String)
     m_colRows(m_lngCurrRow)(m_lngCurrCol).Text = strText
End Property
Public Property Get CellText() As String
   CellText = m_colRows(m_lngCurrRow)(m_lngCurrCol).Text
End Property
```

Below is the Migrated code(Vb.Net)

```
Public Property CellText() As String
    Get
        CellText = m_colRows.Item(m_lngCurrRow)(m_lngCurrCol).Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        m_colRows.Item(m_lngCurrRow)(m_lngCurrCol).Text = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Option Strict On disallows late binding and I need help on modifying the code to work with it on.

Comment: How do you have defined the _m_colRows_ in VB.NET?

Comment: @steve :- I have defined like this :-  Private m_colRows As Collection

Comment: If Item returns an object, you need to cast it to it's proper class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VB6 `Collection` type holds references of type `Object`.  If you wish to use the `.Text` method on members thereof, you will either have to change `ColRows` into a generic collection (e.g. a `List(Of Control())` or else convert the references held in it into `Control` references before use (e.g.

```
Public Property CellText() As String
    Get
        CellText = CType(m_colRows.Item(m_lngCurrRow), Control())(m_lngCurrCol).Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        CellText = CType(m_colRows.Item(m_lngCurrRow), Control())(m_lngCurrCol).Text = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Without seeing more of your code, I can't tell which approach would be easier and/or would yield better results.  I would guess that using a generic collection would likely yield cleaner code, but the VB6-style `Collection` type supports some constructs that the generic ones generally don't, including the ability to modify the collection during enumeration, which can sometimes make porting tricky.

Comment: Thanks a lot supercat.  but the above example is for onvert the references held in it into Control references before use . would you please give me an example  to change ColRows into a generic collection (e.g. a List(Of Control())

Comment: @vandy: Without seeing how you're declaring or using `m_ColRows` I can't really be sure what would be necessary to work with your other code.  The declaration should probably be something like `Dim m_ColRows as New List(Of Control())`, but other changes would most likely be needed as well.  For example, it's been ages since I've used VB6-style collection, but I think its items are numbered 1..n rather than 0..n-1 (as would be the case with `List(of Collection())`, which might [depending upon what else is done with the collection] most easily be dealt with by adding a dummy element zero...

Comment: ...and never using it, or by having code access `.Item(m_lngCurRow-1)`, but could probably best be dealt with by changing code so that `m_lngCurRow` goes from 0 to n-1.  Without seeing the rest of your code, however, it's impossible to say for certain which approach would best fit your needs.

Comment: if VB6 code is like below, what would be your suggestion in VB.Net? 
  Private m_colBookmarks As Collection Private Property Get BookmarkCompID(ByVal strBookmarkNum As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    BookmarkCompID = m_colBookmarks(strBookmarkNum)(COL_ERR_BKMARK_COMP_ID)
End Property

Comment: @vandy: Are you only using numerical IDs in the range 1..N with the collection?  I would suggest looking at replacing it with either a `List(Of Control())` or [`List(Of List(Of Control))`, possibly substituting whatever type of control you're using, if consistent), with the caveat that the indices would need to be adjusted to go from 0..N-1 instead of 1..N.  You'll have to manually find all the places that need adjusting, and the code will be buggy if you miss any, but that approach should yield the nicest code.

Answer (score 1):

The message is correct. `Option Strict` **does** disallow late binding.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30574

You can pick late binding or option strict but you can't have both.

Your only options are to

- Turn off late binding
- Change your code so it doesn't use late binding
- Turn off "option strict"